# Remove Entity Framework's extra lookup of RowVersion columns

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5, rowversion

I need to add a RowVersion column to all my tables.  I need it for reasons like data warehousing (and similar DB only actions).  I don't want to use it for concurrency.

I want Entity Framework to keep working as if the RowVersion column is not there.  But I can't seem to see a way to do that.

When ever I do an update, SQL Profile tells me this is what is being executed:

```
update [dbo].[Widget]
set [WidgetCost] = @0
where ([WidgetId] = @1)

select [RowVersionId]
from [dbo].[Widget]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [WidgetId] = @1
```

If I don't have the RowVersion column on the table then the second select statement does not happen.

**How can I get Entity Framework to just ignore the RowVersionId column?**  If at all possible I would prefer a method that does not require manually editing the csdl/msdl after each update of the model from the database.  (Someone will forget eventually.)

I have tried:

1. Ensuring that the RowVersionId column's Concurrency Mode is set to "None"
2. Deleting the RowVersionId column from the edmx.  (I can't seem to delete it from the model.)

NOTE: As long as I don't update the table in EF's designer (edmx) after I add the column, it works as expected.  So there is something in Entity Framework that this doing this.  (But I can't just lock down my edmx from begin updated after I add this column.)

Comment: Been a while since I used edmx, but can you exclude the columns after refreshing the model?

Comment: What is your problem with `RowVersion` column in Db-First workflow? Is a Concurrency exception thrown?

Comment: @DavidG I can remove it from the editor, but not the model.

Comment: @Alireza my problem is only that it runs that extra query. My application runs in a very performance constrained environment. That extra lookup slows it down too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this a bit more.  If you change the StoreGeneratedPattern for the RowVersion column from "Computed" to "None", then it will not do the extra lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Remove RowVersion field from your model class and it's mapping too